# 2 canvas using the drawImage to center one canvas within the other canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-video

I am trying to center on canvas within another and center it. And I would like it to be responsive, this has proven harder than I thought it would be.

I have this structure.

```
 <div class="photobooth"> // container
<div class="controls">    // just for the CTA btn
  <button class="cta" onClick="takePhoto()">Take Photo of your ID front please. Place the document  within the red border</button>
  <canvas class="blurPhoto" ></canvas> // the big canvas
```

// the small canvas, users should place the docs withing the border of this canvas
       // hidden, this is just necesary to get the data for the canvas

```
<div class="strip">This goes to the database</div>
```

What I want is a full screen background with a blur applied to it. And in the center of that blurry canvas (or it can be the video element, maybe applying a blur to the video element and centering a canvas there would be better?), I want a clear canvas displaying a quasi real time feed of the data on the video element.

The blurred background and the red border of the inner canvas serve as indicators to the user as to where to place the documents(this whole app is a primitive emulator of the Revolut KYC UI).

Now I am not sure what is best, to set all this up with CSS or JS.

```
video {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
width:10%;
height:10%;
filter :blur(1px);
display:none;
}
```

Here I am hiding the video, it does not seem to matter at what % the height and width is set, the JS on the Canvas overrides it anyway.

As I cannot nest Canvas, here I do not know what else to do..

```
.photo { // this is the small canvas which should be centered within the big one
 position:absolute;

 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;

 border:1px red solid;


}

.blurPhoto { big canvas
 position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 filter :blur(10px);
  border:1px red solid;

 }
```

Now as the .photo canvas parent element is the wrapper div, setting position top:100% does not do what I want it to, so I have removed it.

Here I am caching 2 canvas:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('.photo');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasBig = document.querySelector('.blurPhoto');
const ctx2 = canvasBig.getContext('2d');
```

And here is the relevant JS function:

```
function paintToCanvas() {
const width = video.videoWidth;
const height = video.videoHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;


return setInterval(() => {


 ctx.drawImage(video, 0,
    0, width, height);

 ctx2.drawImage(video, 0,
    0, width, height);  // this is overruled by the CSS set on it


 }, 16);
  }
```

So, how do I get this to work.
Should I simply use the video element as background?
Is it possible to have this responsive?

Here is the codepen link, I have changed some of the CSS, but still not happy.

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/GwqxvM

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Put both canvases in a container div and use the % trick to center

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.photo   {
    position: absolute;
    width:50vw;
    height:50vh;
    border:1px red solid;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.blurPhoto { big canvas
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    filter :blur(10px);
    border:1px red solid;
 }
```

Comment: This doe snot really work, for various reasons. This is not a simple CSS centering issue.

Comment: You are making blurPhoto as big as the view, but you are positioning it in a relative way. Are you trying to make it cover the whole window? If you are it needs to be absolute or fixed, or you can't have anything else on the page but it and its decendants. I don't understand exactly what you need to do with the photo, and I'm sorry if you already understand this, but positioning in css is almost always either relative to a parent or absolue, so you either need its parent to have a consistant relative size and position to wherever you want photo to be, or you have to position photo manually.

Comment: yes the blurry photo should take most of the screen, or all. This is just so that the user has the non blurry part to place his docs. And then some of the blurry part serves as background for a button.
Go to the codepen, the thing works, then you will see what I a m trying there.
It is just notreally satisfying and not responsive.

Comment: Yes, I see two red boxes. If I remove the blur from it, I can see the blurPhoto box is centered over the photo box. What does responsive mean to you, in this context? When I think of responsive, most of the time it seems to be used to mean responds to changes quickly. It seems like the thing that slows down changes to your UI, is the * {transition:.5s;} which slows down every change to css properties by half a second. Removing it makes everything work quickly, although it would slow down if the video was added.

Comment: Ah, nono, by responsive I mean responsive canvas on all devices, the speed of the UI is surprisingly ok to me.:-)

Comment: So you are looking for help to make your canvases change their content quicker?